# Is the first daily spin in Bejewelled Blitz rigged?

Tags: bejeweled-blitz

The first daily spin I had after installing the Android version of Bejewelled Blitz netted the top prize of 100,000 coins.  This seemed fairly unlikely, is the first play rigged to give this amount?

Comment: It was not that way for me the first time I played on the Android app.

Comment: I just downloaded and played until I unlocked the daily spin. I also received 100,000 coins on the first spin. P.S: I do actually have stuff to do at work :P

Comment: Decided to try on another Android device and received 100,000 coins again. Not enough evidence to confirm it is rigged, but certainly looks that way.

Comment: Casual games that has daily bonus is usually "rigged" on the first bonus. The reason is to increase the player's interest to continue playing the game (while it also gives the player a boost to progress in some games).