# How do you unlock Daily Spins?

Tags: bejeweled-blitz

I installed Bejewelled Blitz on Android to try and answer a question about [Daily Spins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/125114/181240). I've played 6 games of Bejeweled Blitz, but the Daily Spin option is greyed out with the message "Continue playing to unlock Daily Spin".

How long do I need to play in order to unlock the Daily Spin?

[image: Menu with locked daily spin]